# Call a method from SOAP Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm working on a protocol which is designed to be implemented with SOAP over HTTP. 
WSDL files are provided by a third party.

I used wsdl.exe to generated a proxy class and created a Web Service Project in VS.

```
wsdl.exe yourFile.wsdl /l:CS
```

I got a cs from a unwrapping wsdl.

Snippet:

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute("chargeBoxIdentity")]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute()]
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("/ClearCache", RequestElementName="clearCacheRequest", RequestNamespace="urn://Ocpp/Cp/2012/02/", ResponseElementName="clearCacheResponse", ResponseNamespace="urn://Ocpp/Cp/2012/02/", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("status")]
public abstract ClearCacheStatus ClearCache();
```

- Implementation 1 (Server Side)

A central system (Server) connected to devices. When a device initialized, it sends an authorisation to central system.
And Server response an authorisation message back.
I have already done with Server Side which provides all clients send requests to Server. And Server response the messages.It works well.

- Implementation 2 (Central system send a message to a device)
  [image]

The other part of implementation is a central system need to send message to device (ex. clear devices cache, please see a snippet above). I add those methods to web service as well.

**My questions** are...

1. How can I send a message to devices through a proxy from Web Service?
2. It's impossible to call a method from Web Service sending requests to device? Any suggestions?
3. Or I need to create a project implementing a ClearCache method and format as a SOAP message to trigger?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is a good idea to allow the Central system to directly communicate with the clients (Will create a huge noise in the network if the number of devices is high and the server tries to send several messages)..

A better approach will be to allow all the messages that the server intends to send to the client to be cached locally in the server machine. The clients should periodically communicate with the server using another web service and obtain the cached information that you intend to send to the clients.

you can design a method that sends the guid of the client as a parameter in the web service call.

On the server you maintain a database and keep track of the messages that needs to be sent to the clients.

use a timer object in the clients. On elapse of the timer define a method that communicates with the server by sending its guid. On the server side use this guid as a Primary Key to identify wat messages  need to be sent to the client and then reply that while returning from the message.

The client then uses this return value to decide how to respond.